# UE4 C++ Cannot get UE4 TArray to work with C++ 2DArray

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

I have tried many different approaches giving me a variety of errors to allow my C++ 2D array to work with UE4 TArray.

Header File

[image]

CPP File (initialization part of it at least)

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
TArray<TArray<int> > employeePackingArray;
employeePackingArray.Init(TArray<int>(), n);
```